# Laravel Collection does n't work correctly

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a problem with my collection

```
 $tasks = Bear::all();
 $val = new Collection([]);
 foreach($tasks as $tas){
     $val ->push($tas->id);
 }

 $tasks1 = BearPic::whereIn('bear_id',$val)->get();
 $val2 = new Collection([]);
 foreach($tasks1 as $tas){
     $val ->push($tas->bear_id);
 }
```

my echo on `val` one is

```
[10,11,12,10,10,11,11,12,12]
```

And on `tasks1` is

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "bear_id": 10,
    "picnic_id": 1,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "bear_id": 10,
    "picnic_id": 2,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "bear_id": 11,
    "picnic_id": 1,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "bear_id": 11,
    "picnic_id": 2,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "bear_id": 12,
    "picnic_id": 1,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "bear_id": 12,
    "picnic_id": 2,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}]
```

the second collection returns empty
what might be the problem? I am rather new to laravel this is a tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second collection `val2` is empty simply because you are pushing the values to `val` i.e. the first collection instead of `val2`.

Also, if you insist on not using joins and working on Collections, `pluck` is indeed a quicker solution.

```
$tasks = Bear::all();
$val = $tasks->pluck('id');

$tasks1 = BearPic::whereIn('bear_id', $val)->get();
$val2 = $tasks2->pluck('bear_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wanted to put all of `id` values of `$tasks1` collection to `$val2`, am I correct? If so then you could simply  do like this:

```
$tasks1 = BearPic::whereIn('bear_id',$val)->get();

$val2 = $tasks1->pluck('id');
```